# Channel-specific icon and badges are missing in achievements dropdown on all sites but Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog, stack-overflow-for-teams, favicon

The achievements dropdown on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is pretty complete:

[image]

On other sites, like [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com), the channel-specific icon is missing, and I'm also not seeing the entry for the Mortarboard badge:

[image]

On https://stackexchange.com/, the achievements aren't even shown:

[image]

Comment: There’s actually a white C there.

Comment: C for...teams!...?

Comment: @AndrasDeak C as in Charcoal.

Comment: Ooooh thanks, Glorfindel, I thought this was another "forgot to change channels to teams" bug :(

Comment: Oh, I don't exclude the possibility entirely that it's a C for Channels.

Comment: No, you're right, it depends on the channel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working now for me. Let me know if you're still seeing this bug.

Comment: Hah, I have to convince someone to upvote one of my posts, then :P

Comment: Wait. I just accepted an answer, which gave me +2 reputation, but the event doesn't show in the Achievements inbox *at all*.

Comment: So, i see inbox notifications for my team on SE.com, but i'm also not seeing events in achievements at all. Let me know if something shows up for you delayed. Perf? We will see.

Comment: @Glorfindel For this bug have someone comment on your question/answer. If the icon shows up there, then we should be good. The achievements not showing up are a separate bug we're looking into.

Comment: [Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVscv.png), thanks!

Comment: @Glorfindel Rep changes should be showing up now in the achievements menu on SO.com and will be coming to the menu everywhere later today or so. One correction, everywhere but SE.com. Teams updates won't show there for now. Security issue.

Comment: Yep, they do now. Thanks again! *frantically tries to upvote answer twice*

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it's still different on other sites ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDE36.png)) than on Stack Overflow. There's a gray background on non-SO sites.